# C++ pass enum as parameter

Tags: c++, parameters, enums

If I have a simple class like this one for a card:

```
class Card {
        public:
            enum Suit { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES };
            Card(Suit suit);
    };
```

and I then want to create an instance of a card in another file how do I pass the enum?

```
#include "Card.h"
using namespace std;
int main () {
    Suit suit = Card.CLUBS;
    Card card(suit);
    return 0;
}
```

error: 'Suit' was not declared in this scope

I know this works:

```
#include "Card.h"
using namespace std;
int main () {
    Card card(Card.CLUBS);
    return 0;
}
```

but how do I create a variable of type Suit in another file?

Comment: WTF, Card.CLUBS doesn't give you an error??? I'd think it needs to be Card::CLUBS... x_x

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `Card::Suit` to reference the type when not inside of Card's scope.  ...actually, you should be referencing the suits like that too; I'm a bit surprised that `Card.CLUBS` compiles and I always thought you had to do `Card::CLUBS`.

Comment: use Card.CLUBS as it will match with question.

Answer (score 7):

Suit is part of the class Card's namespace, so try:

```
Card::Suit suit = Card::CLUBS;
```

Comment: OMG that is just not worth the effort. I am going to use an int and put a comment in the code. Can anybody think of a card game where Clubs change, yet a full reference for the enum is needed each time?